# How To read a text file from a folder and convert it into table in MySQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I have a folder that contains 50 text files ,i require a in C# or .NET program that can read these text files and convert them into tables,i want the primary key to be the name of the text file itself.

```
//sample contents of my 1.txt file is as follows
atro
astrology
king
moon
monkey
seven
skin //
```

All the text files contain the information in the same format.
I have written an macro that can read the text files which are in the above mentioned data format and then when i tried to run the macro in Excel i'm getting a error stating that out of memory.

```
enter code here
```

Sub rameshc()
'
' ramesh Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+k
'
Dim nxt_row As Long

```
 'Change Path
Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\roo\Desktop\Volumes\eGo\tags\0\"
Dim strExtension As String

 'Stop Screen Flickering
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ChDir strPath

 'Change extension
strExtension = Dir(strPath & "*.txt")

Do While strExtension <> ""

     'Adds File Name as title on next row
    Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = strExtension

     'Sets Row Number for Data to Begin
    nxt_row = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

     'Below is from a recorded macro importing a text file
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & strPath & strExtension, Destination:=Range("$A$" & nxt_row))
        .Name = strExtension
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
         'Delimiter Settings:
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "="

        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    strExtension = Dir
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub
Sub ramesh()
'
' ramesh Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+l
'
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
End Sub

Comment: You could read all files in a folder and generate SQL code that would create each of the tables with data. All you would have to do then is to copy-paste generated SQL and execute it in MySQL.

Comment: @rameshkumar I am new to this so i request you to brief me about the procedure

Comment: What is your actual question? Where are you stuck? We can't write this program for you.

Comment: @ramesh kumar My question is that i have a folder that contains text files in it ,i want to read the data in those text files and then convert the text file contents into table format in MYsql

Comment: Is there 50 columns in that table. What is he table format...? give us some idea about the table.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html go from there, took less than 2 seconds to Google

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is to:

1. Create a console application. Search your file inside your folder. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ezwyzy7b.aspx
2. Make a direct connection using *System.Data.SqlClient*. http://www.bigresource.com/MS_SQL--Problem-with-simple-sqlclient-database-acces--AVufrVBE.html
3. Write your *insert* statement. Iterate your file. And do a insert for each one. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

You'll be using something like this to read your files:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:/YourFile.txt");

        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            *Insert Statement*
        }
```

Comment: @IvanIvković you were right. Here is a good sample on how to connect c# to MySQL. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL. The code will be the same by the way.